# Finding operator from minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

While doing questions of minimal polynomial, I came across these particular kind of questions:

> Give an example of an operator on $\mathbb{C}^4$ whose characteristic and minimal polynomials both equal $z(z-1)^2(z-1)$.

Now finding operator which satisfies characteristic polynomial is simple but for minimal polynomial it becomes really tough sometimes. So, I was wondering if there is a standard way of solving these questions?

Comment: Are you sure about the polynomial?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial $P\in\mathbb C[X]$ can be written :
$$P(X) = (X-\lambda_1)^{n_1}\ldots(X-\lambda_k)^{n_k}$$
for some complex numbers $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_l$ and natural integers $n_1,\ldots,n_k$.

Since $(X-\lambda_i)^{n_i}$ and $(X-\lambda_j)^{n_j}$ are relatively prime when $i\neq j$, if we find matrice $A_1,\ldots,A_k$ whose respective minimal and characteristic polynomials are $(X -\lambda_1)^{n-1}, \ldots, (X-\lambda_k)^{n_k}$,  we can take the matrix we want of the form :
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 & \ldots  & 0\\
0 &A_2 & & \vdots \\
\vdots&&\ddots &0\\
0&\ldots & 0&A_k\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, it is not hard to see that the minimal polynomial of :
$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & 1& \ddots  & \vdots  \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots \\
&&0&\lambda&1\\
0&\ldots&&0&\lambda
\end{pmatrix}\in\mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$$
is $(X-\lambda)^n$.

In your case, with $P(X) = X(X-1)^3$, we can take :
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$